# Sqlite Point type column missing after successfuly creating and applying EF core Migration

Tags: .net, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I have created this entity:

```
public class Location
{  
    ...      
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public Point Point { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}
```

and then configure it:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Location>().Property(m => m.Point)
                .HasColumnType("point").HasSrid(4326);
```

and this is my dbcontext config:

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlite().AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlite("Data Source=" + Configuration["Connections:DefaultConnection"]),
        x => { x.UseNetTopologySuite(); });
});
```

I successfuly created and applied a migration, The entity is created but The 'Point' column is missing when I see this DB with Sqlite viewers.

There is some output from the Migration that is applied (in Package Manager Console):

```
Applying migration '20220705163739_GEO3'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT AddGeometryColumn('Locations', 'Point', 4326, 'point', -1, 0);
```

I use .net 6.05 EF core Sqlite packages. Why there is no Point column in Sqlite viewer?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to create the point column with its table:

first I define entity property as 'string':

```
public string Point { get; set; }
```

and configuration as 'geography':

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyGeo>().Property(m => m.Point)
                .HasColumnType("geography").HasSrid(4326);
```

Then I create and apply a Migration.
After successful migrate change Property Type to **Point** and also the configuration : **.HasColumnType("point")**